# Is my understanding of anti-symmetry and symmetry correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I'm struggling with understanding relations on equations, especially symmetric and anti-symmetric.

Here's my understanding, please let me know if it's correct or not:

The relation R:

- is reflexive iff (a,a) ∈ R
- is symmetric iff (a,b) and (b,a) ∈ R
- is anti-symmetric if (a,b) ∈ R and (b,a) NOT in ∈ R
- is transitive if (a,b) ∈ R and (b,c) ∈ R, then (a,c) ∈ R

Example for symmetric and anti-symmetric:

Symmetric: (1,1), (2,1), (1,2)

Anti-symmetric: (1,2), (2,3), (4,3) (would it be anti-symmetric if I included ex. (2,2)?)

Is this correct?

Comment: Often antisymmetric is stated as: For all $a,b$, if $(a,b)\in R$ and $(b,a)\in R$, then $a=b$. The way you have stated it, it should be emphasized that this would hold for all $a, b$ with $a \ne b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there should be $\forall $ statements (e.g. reflexive is $\forall a$, $(a,a)\in R$ and transitive is $\forall a,b,c$, $(a,b)\in R\land (b,c)\in R\implies (a,c)\in R$).

Secondly, for your definition of antisymmetric, $a$ and $b$ must be distinct. We can have e.g. $(1,1)$ in an antisymmetric relation.

So your example of a symmetric relation is correct and your example of an anti-symmetric relation would be correct even if you added $(2,2)$ to the relation.

Comment: Thank you, I finally understand it!